# How can I detect if the color of a button changes because CSS or JavaScript event when I put mouse on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

*How can I detect if color of bottom change because CSS or JavaScript event when I put mouse on button?*

**My solution that not good enough:**

1. create function that will listen to JavaScript events
2. check with firebug if element have CSS 'hover' rule

Problems in my solution:

1. Can't detect which event happen before CSS or JavaScript
2. Not Auto check

Please give better solution if you have.
(I working with jQuery)

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want this information?

Comment: because I need to disable hover on element in some cases not always

Answer (score 2):

You can check with Firebug which events are fired in JavaScript. Go to the Console and click "Profile". Then move your mouse over the button and you will see the JavaScript event show up.

Comment: You can go to the HTML Tab and select "Style" on the right hand pane. Then navigate to the element that you are interested in and you will see all styles that apply to the element. You can then look for hover styles etc.

Comment: This I write in my solution. I asking about better way.And how its solves:Can't detect which event happen before css or javascript